# pdf download on page load event -asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have an aspx page when a link is clicked it will redirect to another page, and when that other page loads I want to download pdf automatically (in page_load).
I wrote the download code in page_load.
It is downloading the pdf, but it is not redirecting, what did I miss?

'download code (page2.aspx)

```
Response.Buffer = True
Response.Expires = 0
Response.CacheControl = "NO-CACHE"
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.ClearContent()
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf"
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0")
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=ViewPDF.pdf")
Response.BinaryWrite(pdf)
Response.Flush()
Response.Close()
```

'below is the redirect code (page1.aspx)

```
Dim url As String = "page2.aspx"

Response.Redirect(url, false)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clarify your question.

Comment: There are a few ways to accomplish this. Instead of seeing the download code (which you said works), it would be better to show the part doing the redirect.